# How can we split a string and apply between condition or less than greater condition in stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure and there are multiple filters there is a filter of salary range I am getting input min and max as string separated by comma like `200,5000` it's working fine, but now I need to include multiple ranges with separated like `2,400|400,800` and I need to split them and add condition between or less than greater than - please help.

```
IF (@Salary <> '')      
BEGIN
    SELECT @salaryStr = '>= ' + 
                        REPLACE(@Salary, ',' , ' AND Salary <= ') + '';
    SET @query = @query + ' AND Salary  ' + @salaryStr + ' '
END
```

It's working fine for one range, but I need something to work with multiple ranges as mentioned above. I am sending ranges as string `2,400|400,700` - how can I achieve this? I tried to use `string_split` function of SQL Server, but could not get it to do what I need - not sure how to use that in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take `'2,400|400,800','|'` as an example:

```
select a.value      as range,
       min(b.value) as from_value,
       max(b.value) as to_value
  from string_split('2,400|400,800','|') a
  cross apply string_split(a.value,',') b
 group by a.value;
```

Result:

```
range  |from_value|to_value|
-------+----------+--------+
2,400  |2         |400     |
400,800|400       |800     |
```

You may want to CAST from/to_value(s) to proper data types

EDIT: to apply the values to range condition, in this example, the multiple ranges are continuous. Therefor, pick the min() `from_value` and the max() `to_value` for the dynamic SQL:

```
select min(b.value) as from_value,
       max(b.value) as to_value
  from string_split('2,400|400,800','|') a
  cross apply string_split(a.value,',') b;
```

```
from_value|to_value|
----------+--------+
2         |800     |
```